# How do I get Events associated with a Pod via the API?

Tags: kubernetes

When I do a `kubectl describe <pod>`, the bottom section has an "Events" section, displaying Events related to that pod.  For example, an event with Reason "failedScheduling", with the message "Failed for reason PodFitsResources and possibly others"

How can I query the API to return that list of events?

If I call `/api/v1/namespaces/<ns>/pods/<pod_name>`, it doesn't return any Events. If I try the `/api/v1/events` endpoint, I can specify a `labelSelector` parameter, but the name of the pod isn't a label of the Event, though it is in the `object.involvedObject.name` field.

I could request the entire Event stream and filter out the few Events that interest me client-side, but that seems like overkill.  `kubectl` is able to do it, so I figure there must be some way that I'm missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think events support a fieldSelector for the involved object kind and name

You can also turn the verbosity level on kubectl up to 8 to see network traces to see what it is doing

Comment: Ah, excellent!  I didn't know about the verbosity trick to see all the API calls being made.  That solved the mystery!

Comment: FYI, in case you're curious, it's calling the `/v1/namespaces/<ns>/events` endpoint, with a `fieldSelector` parameter of `involvedObject.name=<pod>,involvedObject.uid=<pod_uid>`

Comment: Thanks @JonM, that's super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still wondering how `kubectl` gets the events along with the `describe` command, then have a look at the following:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b6a0718858876bbf8cedaeeb47e6de7e650a6c5b/pkg/kubectl/describe/versioned/describe.go#L242

If you see what's happening is that they first get the details of the resource requested (see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b6a0718858876bbf8cedaeeb47e6de7e650a6c5b/pkg/kubectl/describe/versioned/describe.go#L235 ) and then they get all the events from that namespace and filter out the events for the requested resource. See Line 242 in the same link.

So they are not using some other undocumented API or other ways, What you thought as overkill is what they are doing.